# Spring: H2 Database persistence

Tags: java, spring, persistence, h2

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./src/main/resources/asnDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.user=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I have a data.sql which is loaded when I start the spring-project.

How do I alter the application.properties to make the database persistent?

For now it always makes a new one. It doesn't work neither if I change the `ddl.auto=create` to `ddl.auto=update`. I know that `ddl.auto=create` overwrites my DB, but I have no idea how to make it persistent.

In the data.sql there are 3 Insert-Statements and when I run the project I already have 3 inserts in my DB. Then I insert a new one via my UI and quit the project. When i re-run the project there are just the initial 3 inserts. But there should be 4 inserts.

Comment: if when you quit the project your database contains only the 3 original inserts then check that after you do the insert through the UI the rows is saved and is not rolledback.

Comment: so I don't have to change anything in my code?

Comment: How many rows there are when you stop the app without re-running it again?

Comment: i don't have access to the h2-database, I start the project via `mvn spring-boot:run` so when I stop this the "server" is down.

Comment: There you have your answer. The problem is that you database is in-memory. Once the app is stopped all gets destroyed. Once the app starts 3 rows are added as part of the start up process. Make your database be persisted to the file system

Comment: I already did. My problem is when i start the app it loads the data.sql file and rewrites the my database-file. Can I alter some settings so the data.sql won't be load when the database-file isn't empty?

Comment: Sorry I missread your question Try adding property ´spring.datasource.initialize=false´

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138363/discussion-between-steveohio-and-artemisian).

Comment: Hello @SteveOhio I am having same issue . Did you managed to get it resolved?

Answer (score 36):

You miss the auto-reconnect feature

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE

So that for example works:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: when spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update ensure there is no separate schema.sql file to create the table structure. It will delete the old table with the data and create an empty table each time the application is started.

Comment: You all are very knowledgeable folks !! hats off!

Answer (score 16):

persistence comes from property ***spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto*** being ***update*** instead of being **create**