# How to persist data from containerized h2?

Tags: spring, docker, h2

I have simple spring boot application that runs with embedded h2 that stores information in file. I used h2 because i wanted simplest possible solution, this application is just for learning docker.
Here are important bits:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:${user_home}/images_api/imagesmetadata/h2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

I run it using this command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 \
-e USER_HOME=/images_api \
-v $HOME/images_api/files:/images_api/files \
-v $HOME/images_api/imagesmetadata:/images_api/imagesmetadata \
image_api
```

after application restart database is empty and nothing is persisted.
What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring: H2 Database persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857731/spring-h2-database-persistence)

Comment: Not really, outside of docker everything is persisted fine. Only when i run app in docker nothing gets persisted.

Comment: This is an important information that was not present in your question.  However that page recommends `AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE` and it is not present in your cfg.